# Извлечь ключ из вложенных словарей

Tags: python, python-3.x

как перeменной присвоить значение `2400013210640269` из этого

```
{'success': 1, 'return': {'2400013210640269': {'pair': 'eth_btc', 'type': 'sell', 'amount': 0.08801235, 'rate': 0.036, 'timestamp_created': '1617786759', 'status': 0}}}
```

помимо этого

```
for key in yobit_orders:
    #    print(key)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
yobit_orders = {'success': 1, 'return': {'2400013210640269': {'pair': 'eth_btc', 'type': 'sell', 'amount': 0.08801235, 'rate': 0.036, 'timestamp_created': '1617786759', 'status': 0}}}

print(yobit_orders['return'].popitem()[0])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
yobit_orders = {'success': 1, 'return': {'2400013210640269': {'pair': 'eth_btc', 'type': 'sell', 'amount': 0.08801235, 'rate': 0.036, 'timestamp_created': '1617786759', 'status': 0}}}

print(list(yobit_orders['return'])[0])
```

Вывод:

```
2400013210640269
```

Ответ на дополнительный вопрос:

```
yobit_orders = {'success': 1, 'return': {'1400013210748376': {'pair': 'eth_btc', 'type': 'buy', 'amount': 0.0033, 'rate': 0.03034999, 'timestamp_created': '1617792655', 'status': 0}, '2400013210747464': {'pair': 'eth_btc', 'type': 'sell', 'amount': 0.08801235, 'rate': 0.036, 'timestamp_created': '1617792611', 'status': 0}}}
mytype = 'sell'
order_id = [k for k in yobit_orders['return'] if yobit_orders['return'][k]['type'] == mytype]
print(order_id)
```

Вывод:

```
['1400013210748376']
```

Comment: можно убрать `.keys()`

Comment: @Danis Да, точно, добавил итерирование потом и забыл, что можно убрать теперь )

Comment: {'success': 1, 'return': {'1400013210748376': {'pair': 'eth_btc', 'type': 'buy', 'amount': 0.0033, 'rate': 0.03034999, 'timestamp_created': '1617792655', 'status': 0}, '2400013210747464': {'pair': 'eth_btc', 'type': 'sell', 'amount': 0.08801235, 'rate': 0.036, 'timestamp_created': '1617792611', 'status': 0}}}
а как из этого переменной присвоить 1400013210748376 если  'type': 'buy' и переменной 2400013210747464 если 'type': 'sell' ?

Comment: Благодарю, из списка знаю (вродь попроще), а вот из словаря в словаре словарём незнал. ;-)